# Validate date of one column greater than with another column in yii

Tags: yii

I have a form which has date_of_purchasing and expiry_date. I need to check date_of_purchasing should not be greater than expiry_date. How can i write this validation rule in model.

Im using YII framework. And im new for this framework.

Answer (score 1):

**Yii2**

This should work if the compared column comes from the same table.

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
            [
                ['date_end'], 
                'compare', 
                'compareAttribute' => 'date_start', 
                'operator' => '>=', 
                'type' => yii\validators\DateValidator::TYPE_DATE, 
                'message' => 'Date end has to be greater than date start', 
                'enableClientValidation' => false
            ],
            // other rules...
    ];
}
```

Don't forget to set enableClientValidation to false because Yii2 can't check the other date without a server side request.

Other configuration options [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-datevalidator).

> PS. I decided to update this thread 3+ years after because it remains
> one of the first StackOverflow results on Google Search for this argoument.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `CompareValidator` at this link: [Compare](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#comparing-date-values) .